# Max Block Height for a Redstone Contraption

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

What's the max height of blocks for a redstone contraption to still work even I'm in the surface below?

Like if I build a pillar to the max height of blocks and build a redstone contraption there, is it still going to work even I'm on the surface below?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Chunks are 16×256×16 and server-side they are always loaded either completely or not at all (client-side they are rendered in 16×16×16 sections, but that's just how they are displayed).